# Testing pdf/excel content with C#

Tags: selenium2, selenium-webdriver, c#, excel

Our site has a good number of reports that are using `SSRS`,`Crystal` and `Excel`. We are using `C#` with `Selenium WebDriver`. I have been searching for the best practices and best ways and tools to test the content of those report. I need to test `pdf/excel` content or both depending on the report I am testing. I know Selenium does not have native support for this kind of testing. My question is what kind of tool I can integrate with Selenium to accomplish that? Open source preferred.

In summary:

1. How to test pdf/excel content with C#?
2. What are the best practices?

Answer (score 3):

I think I can point you in the right direction for MS Word, at least.

You can use the [Office Interop Assemblies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15s06t57.aspx) in C#.

[Here](http://www.dotnetperls.com/word) is an example from .Net Pearls:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    // Open a doc file.
    Application application = new Application();
    Document document = application.Documents.Open("C:\\word.doc");

    // Loop through all words in the document.
    int count = document.Words.Count;
    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        // Write the word.
        string text = document.Words[i].Text;
        Console.WriteLine("Word {0} = {1}", i, text);
    }
    // Close word.
    application.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That sounds promising. I will definitely look into

Answer (score 2):

Webdriver is a browser manipulation API only and as such the ability to read office or PDF files is out of scope of its capabilities, but the office interop libraries will allow you to read data from office files in C#, and there will be similar libraries for reading PDF documents.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I know that and I mentioned that in my question. I was looking for the libraries available to accomplish that.

Comment: No worries like I mentioned, the office interop libraries should be fine for reading office files, and I have heard good things about the PdfSharp.Net library for inspecting PDF files. Hope that helps

Comment: Will check this out